# No package mssql-tools available

Tags: centos, repository

i want to install mssql-server in the centos 7 server ... i did the procedure before on other server before how ever for this one i could not able to install mssql-tools .. the mssql server is installed and works fine.

what i am doing is i config the repo

```
sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo
```

and then install

```
sudo yum install -y mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
```

the unixODBC-devel is fine. how ever i get this output

```
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository packages-microsoft-com-prod is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.docker.ru
 * epel: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * extras: mirror.docker.ru
 * updates: mirror.corbina.net
No package mssql-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

i searched on the part of message that says

> Repository packages-microsoft-com-prod is listed more than once in the
> configuration

however i am not sure but i think i got the same in previous server and every thing installed fine. any way i did some procedure suggested for that and still i get the same message.

this is my yum.repos.d directory

```
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Media.repo          epel.repo            mssql-server.repo
CentOS-CR.repo         CentOS-Sources.repo        epel-testing.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo          microsoft-prod.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  CentOS-x86_64-kernel.repo  msprod.repo
```

msprod.repo is the one.

Comment: I found https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15 and while it's recent (09/21/2021), it only talks about RHEL8 -- not 7. Perhaps they don't offer that package for RHEL/CentOS 7 (any more)?

Comment: i did the same procedure ..i dont think  so, many servers still prefer centos 7 , this procedure for centos 7 rhel also works recently for me

Comment: It would be interesting to do a `yum list available`, filtered for the Microsoft repo, to check for this package.  Try it from one of the servers that worked recently as well. Maybe this new server needs a `yum clean all`?

Answer (score 0):

okay i removed all microsoft packages repositored in

> /etc/yum.repos.d

and then did the procedure of reposit and install.

for more information and explanation you can check [this](https://learningintheopen.org/2019/09/15/yum-warning-repository-packages-microsoft-com-prod-is-listed-more-than-once-in-the-configuration/)